# limit function $f$ of $\{F_n\}$. $F_n=nx^n(1-x^2) $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, sequence-of-function

> Find the limit function $f$ of $\{F_n\}$. $F_n=nx^n(1-x^2) $

My solution:

For $x=\pm1, 0, F_n=0 \implies f(0)=f(1)=f(-1)=0$.

For $|x|>0$. we have
$$(1-x^2)\lim_{n\to\infty} nx^n=\infty\text{ , if }x>1$$

and $$(1-x^2)\lim_{n\to\infty} nx^n=-1^n\infty\text{ if }x<-1$$

For $0<x< 1$:we can find $n_0$ such that:
\begin{align}
&\dfrac{1}{n_0+1}\leq x\leq\dfrac{1}{n_0}\\
&\dfrac{n}{(n_0+1)^n}\leq nx^n\leq\dfrac{n}{(n_0)^n}\\
&\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n}{(n_0+1)^n}=0\leq \lim_{n\to\infty}nx^n\leq\lim_{n\to\infty}\dfrac{n}{(n_0)^n}=0\\
\end{align}
By the squeeze theorem, $\lim_{n\to\infty}nx^n=0$

Hence $\{F_n\}$ converges pointwise to $f=0$ on the interval $[-1,1]$

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct, though I'm not sure I would use $n_0$ for that number - if $x$ is greater than $1/2$, then you can't take $n_0$ to be an integer, and the use of "$n$" suggests an integer.

Comment: @Reese I meant $n_0$ to be an integer. if x>1/2, then $\dfrac{1}{2}\leq x< 1$, no?

Comment: I think that's all right!

Comment: @MAS Yes, but then $n_0 = 1$ and the final step of your limit doesn't work - $\lim_{n \to \infty}\frac{n}{1^n}$ is not $0$. You'll need to either have a special case for it, or permit $n_0$ to be a non-integer in that case.